# Confusion in a generic code

Tags: java, list, generics

```
List<? extends someObject> list
List<? extends Comparable<? super T>> list
```

I cannot understand the second code. As i understand from the first code,it stores any object that extends some object but in the second code does that mean it stores interface?

Comment: Maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java

Comment: The second list store any objects that implement the Comparable interface

Answer (score 0):

The first is a *list of somethings that are at least `SomeObject`*. It might be the case that you *can not* insert `SomeObject` in the list, if it is a list of a true subclass. Look at it this way:

```java
List<? extends Animal> list
```

This is a *list of somethings that are at least `Animal`*. It might be the case, that this is a *list of cats*, or a *list of dogs*. We don't know, hence the `?`. In any case, we know we can get at least`Animal`s out of the list, but we can not *insert* because we don't know the exact type in the list.

The second is a *list of comparable implementations (or derived interfaces) that apply to `T` or some superclass*. All objects in this list can therefore be used to compare `T` objects. But of course, same as before, we can not be sure what exact type of `Comparable` the list uses as items, so we can not add anything, we can only read it in this form.

Edit: expanding on `Comparable<? super T>`: It may seem counter-intuitive to use `super` instead of `extends`. It is because if you want to compare two things, you can do it by comparing the thing itself *or any higher category* of the thing. So, if I want to compare *dogs*, it is enough for me to know how to compare *animals*. If I can compare *animals* I can compare any animal, including dogs, cats, etc. If I however only know how to compare *cats* I might not know how to compare *dogs*. So if you want to find somebody to compare `T`, you have to look for somebody who can compare `T`, or any *superclass* of `T`.

Comment: I added explanation for `Comparable<? super T>`.